# Style an EntryCell Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an android custom renderer for a Xamarin Forms EntryCell control.  As far as I can tell the EntryCell is a combination of an input and a label. I would like to modify the following properties:

1. Font of the EntryCell label
2. Color of the EntryCell Label
3. TextSize of the EntryCell Label
4. Color of the text of the input control

I have been able to change the colour and size of the EntryCell input using the code below

```
public class CustomEntryCellRenderer : EntryCellRenderer
{
    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context) as EntryCellView;

        if (cell != null)
        {
            var textField = cell.EditText as TextView;

            textField.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 20);
            textField.SetTextColor(Color.FromHex("#FF8800").ToAndroid());

        }

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Can you please let me know how I access the label part of the EntryCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to access label part of `EntryCell`.
You can use `SetLabelTextColor` to set its color.
If you really need to change the font as well, you could use `ViewCell` instead of `EntryCell` and define `Label` and `Entry` separately inside its template. In this case you probably will be able to set all the things you need without using custom renderer.